# how to filter hashmap and find 1st occurance

Tags: java, arrays, conditional-statements

i have converted my hashmap to json as i dont know what itt looks like in java

so my hashmap looks like

```
{"1":[true,false],
"2":[true,true],
"3":[true]}
```

i need to get the first occurance of all true in the array list in a single key

in this case its 2 is the 1st occurance

so if there is an occurance   ///do something   else //do somethig else

```
   hm.forEach((key, value) -> {

            for (Object object : value) {

                   boolean b = (boolean)object;
                   if(!b){
                   break;
                    }else{
                       System.out.println(key+"->"+b);
                   }

            }
});
```

i tried something like this but im getting lost in the mix  here its testing alotall the cases

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: post your json.

Comment: i did i used gson   its right at the top    i used Gson().toJson(hm);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the snippet below.

```
hm.forEach((key, value) -> {
            boolean allTrue=true;
                        for (Object object : value) {
                            allTrue = (boolean)object;
                            if(!allTrue){ //stop if you found a false in the true/false array
                                break;
                            }
                        }//out of the inner iteration
                        if(allTrue){//if this variable is true, it means the above iteration had all values true
                            //do your stuff
                            break;
                        }
                        allTrue=true; //reset
            });
```

Comment: the break part is not working   casue for some reason is not allowed in a lambda foreach loop

Comment: could some one help with this  i need to know how to break if variable is true i cant break out inisde lambda

Comment: i used this solution but heavily modified.

Comment: What modifications did you need? I'll update the answer accordingly

Comment: nono this answer is fine  it served the main purpouse ...i have just modified it to my usage  thaks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this schema

```
hm.entrySet().stream().filter(SomeClass::isAllBoolean)
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);

private static boolean isAllBoolean(Map.Entry<String, List<Boolean>> values) {

}
```

`SomeClass` is a class where `isAllBoolean` method is located.

Comment: will this return true for 2nd key or for all keys cause i need it to show me 2nd key as  values in list of 2nd key are true

Comment: @ReubenGomes for the 2nd key only

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you need a `filter` to check for an all-true boolean array, a `findFirst` to find the first one and a `get` to handle the fact that `findFirst` returns an `Optional`.

```
public void test(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Boolean[]> hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm.put("1", new Boolean[]{true, false});
    hm.put("2", new Boolean[]{true, true});
    hm.put("3", new Boolean[]{true});
    Map.Entry<String, Boolean[]> first = hm.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(es -> allTrue(es.getValue()))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
    System.out.println(first.getKey()+" -> "+ Arrays.toString(first.getValue()));
}

private boolean allTrue(Boolean[] a) {
    for (Boolean b : a) {
        if (!b) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

prints

> 2 -> [true, true]

BTW: The order of iteration of a `Map` is not defined so you are relying on undocumented features by trying to capture the `first` one.

Comment: Also you will have an exception, if the element doesn't exist. He can use `LinkedHashMap` :)

Comment: @v.ladynev FTFY

Comment: Now it is here: `System.out.println`

Comment: @v.ladynev LOL!